# Using nonetheless - "Her view of life seemed a little offbeat. NONETHELESS, I couldn't judge her."

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Is *nonetheless* used correctly in this paragraph?

> Her view of life seemed a little offbeat. **Nonetheless**, I couldn’t judge
>   her. My intentions had never been good, either.

If *nonetheless* is not the word, what's a better option?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Another word that will also work there is "still".

That said, I'd have another look at "offbeat"; it probably makes more sense with more context from earlier sentences, but "offbeat", to my ear at least, is not an inherently negative term, which makes the comparison "my intentions had never been good, either" read a little less fluently.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use *nevertheless*:

> Her view of life seemed a little offbeat. **Nevertheless**, I couldn’t judge her. My intentions had never been good, either.

If you check the definitions of [***nonetheless***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/nonetheless) or [***nevertheless***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/nevertheless), one of each is *in spite of that*, which works well.

> Her view of life seemed a little offbeat. **In spite of that**, I couldn’t judge her. My intentions had never been good, either.